# Process of creating form in Django?

Tags: django

Django is really flexible. The simple html form can be used and processed in Django. But while going through the Django documentation I find that there are numerous ways to write a form in Django. The best I find is to create a `forms.py` and then create a template for it and process using views. Is this the right approach? I think it's way too easy to validate the form and use it in template using this approach. But I am confused where to apply the validation rules in this process. I want to use less Javascript as possible.

Answer (score 0):

For validation you can specify them by

- while defining field using `validators` attribute
- by implementing `clean_field()` method in form
- or `clean()` method in form for multiple field dependent validation.

The validation will be done when you call `form.is_valid()` method in the view where you are processing the form.

Here is more detailed documentation. [Form and field validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Also, is it the good approach to play with forms in Django?

Comment: @user1881957, I don't get what do you mean by that.